# Pronunciation rules for 'b/v'

Tags: pronunciación, betacismo

What are the entire set of criteria that decide how 'b/v' are pronounced in Spanish?

I see [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/pronouncing-the-spanish-b-and-v-3079534) and [here](https://studyspanish.com/pronunciation/listen-and-repeat/letter_bv) that 'b/v' are pronounced like the 'b' sound when it is the first letter of a word or when it follows a 'm' or 'b'.

However, the pronunciation of 'v' in 'vivo' is closer to 'v' than 'b' as seen [here](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/vivo) whereas it should be pronounced like 'bibo' based on the rule that I've mentioned above.

Is there any other rule that I may have missed?

Comment: V and B always sound the same (they're are no words for which switching the letters will change their pronunciation except for some English influenced dialects like PR Spanish where a small effect has been occasionally noted). The better question is how V/B sounds in a given position.

Comment: I've reframed my question now.

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.se]! Note, the [tour] and [help] sections give a helpful introduction to the [se] approach. We believe that this is a duplicate of a questions that has already been answered in the stack. If you think that is not the case, feel free to explain why the preexisting questions and its answers do not fully address your question and flag to reopen. Don't hesitate to ask for help if you need it. Thanks and welcome again.